Does Raft follower store leader ID? If not, how does it redirect requests to leader?
Referring to this table depicted in the Raft paper, I did not find where do followers memorize the leader in any form such as identifier, physical addr, etc. Instead, I only find the leader ID in appendEntries, which, however, seems not to be saved anywhere.  
Could anyone kindly teach:

If, like the table shows, followers do not save info regarding current leader, how do followers redirect the requests sent to them to the leader?

If otherwise, how is the leader info saved in followers' side? is it an identifier alike thing or actual address?


